# Any special technique for case control data where # control matches can vary per case (up to 3 matches per case)?

Tags: weighted-regression, case-control-study

I have case control data, of cancer cases and healthy controls (1 row per participant). I am doing 3 rounds of matching where round 1 does 1 match per case, round two does another match per case and round 3 does another match per case. I do it this way as i want to make sure that everyone has at least 1 match (which doesn't happen if i do it all at once with a 1:3 setting).

As a result I am left with data where among the cases some have 1 match only while others have 2 or 3 control matches. My general direction for analysis is that i have to use conditional logistic regression but i am not sure how to account for the "differences" in control matches. Should i introduce this as a confounder variable (one "Max matches" variable of 3 categories: 1,2,3) or should i use weights if that is an option with conditional logistic regression models? Please advise!!